# Form post problem because of ajax navigation using asp.net mvc with jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-mobile

I have a login form in the inner pages but because jQuery Mobile uses AJAX navigation I am not able to post that form when the page is AJAX loaded. But if I put `rel="external"` in the login link at home page the login form is posted easily but then i lose the cool features provided by jQuery Mobile. Is there any way to post the form while not using `rel="external"` at the home page?

Comment: Jquerry Mobile should be able to post forms. Can you give some example code for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Disable AJAX form submission on the login form. Per the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-sample.html):

> To prevent form submissions from being automatically handled with Ajax, add the data-ajax="false" attribute to the form element. You can also turn off Ajax form handling completely via the ajaxFormsEnabled global config option.